# Is it safe to use code from code.jquery.com for long-term application?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am using Ajax / jquery on a webpage i am designing...  in order for it to function, i include (at the top of my page) the javascript at: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js

This works great and all, but i have a fear that
1) the code might get changed without me knowing, then i encounter problems and try to debug for days / hours before finding that the code at this site changed

2) the website is no longer used / specific code no longer hosted years from now

So would it be safer to save that javascript file onto my server, and access it from there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use either a [Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx) or [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html) CDN.  It will be much faster, it will be cached for a lot of your users and it's guaranteed to be there, as opposed to the jQuery link you include.

Comment: Recommending Microsoft's CDN is terrible, while it's much less popuar than jQuery itself's one:
See [this article](http://encosia.com/6953-reasons-why-i-still-let-google-host-jquery-for-me/): "Want to know how many top 1,000 sites use the Microsoft CDN for any jQuery-related script? Answer: 1 (Microsoft.com)"

Comment: Seriously? This was 3.5 years ago

Comment: What is the problem if your answer is from 2011? That was the time when Microsoft CDN wa knew by some people, and I insist it's terrible to recommend someone to use it even at that time. If you are interested in the current scenario, nowadays Microsoft CDN [isn't taken in consideration anymore](http://trends.builtwith.com/cdn).

Comment: There are probably answers on SO that recommend upgrading to jQuery 1.4 for some improvements performance, or arguing that one should stick to Linq to SQL instead of using Entity Framework 2.0.  The point being - when reading an answer look at the date it was posted to determine if it's still viable.  Of course MS CDN is crap now, but back 3.5 years ago, when their "partnership" with jQuery was newly announced it wasn't such a horrible idea.

Comment: In times where IPv6 becomes popular for many acces-providers is is adviseable to use an IPv6 enabled CDN (Google) or to include a parachute if something goes wrong with the CDN. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15627662/2022209

Answer (score 4):

http://code.jquery.com is jQuery's CDN (provided by Media Temple). The code at `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js` will **never** change; jQuery will release a new version (which will be at a different URL), if anything needs to change (which happens all the time; version 1.5b was released today).

The jQuery guys know what they're doing, and they setup a CDN so people can easily link to jQuery. They're just as (un)likely to bring down the CDN as Google and Microsoft are at bringing theirs down.

See http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery for more information.

Having said that, it would seem the Google hosted version (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js), is referenced more in websites; this leads to a small performance advantage as far as your users are concerned, as the file has more chance of being cached.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe, notice the version number?  As jQuery is updated then that version number will change.

Of course using a CDN will always mean that it's *possible* for the content delivery network to go out of business.  But that's the case with any non directly controlled server.

You of course could use the Google CDN for jQuery, I highly recommend it.

Relevant:
http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js is down right now, some of my sites seems broken. Use google instead

Comment: Any CDN is potentially a point a failure.  Just as I stated in this answer.  Even google.

Comment: code.jquery.com it's not safe. That was the point of the original question. If someone start a long-term application I guess using google's cdn must be the choosed option, but that is my humble opinion

Comment: *All* CDNs have the possibility of outages. I pointed that out in my original answer as well as recommended Google.  However Google's is also not "safe" by the definition of: will always be up when my project is up" and has gone down before.