# code.jquery.com unresponsive from specific IP. do they throttle?

Tags: jquery

Today we had an interesting issue where code.jquery.com was unresponsive from one of our ip addresses.

I was just wondering if they have throttling or usage limits, or if anyone else has had any problems connecting to their site.

It is especially problematic, because it means that any site we browse to that needs to pull libraries from code.jquery.com, also doesn't load or is slow to load depending on how they've included the library. (ie. it just gets stuck trying to download the jquery***.js component).

Hope someone can offer some clues. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've never run into any issues with throttling in my experience, and I know don't know of any throttling implemented.

I've started to use a local fallback in the event of these issues just so things continue to operate. You can do that by doing something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!window.jQuery)
{
    document.write('<script src="/assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

Just update the local version with the CDN version if you ever update the versions. This will give you the best of both worlds, a CDN version, and a local version so things continue to work no matter what.

Comment: Cool idea.  Our own code uses the google library links for the most part, but that local fallback is a good idea. (In regards to the problem I had: It was another library/site that made us notice the connection problem, so we can't just edit it ;( ;) ).

Comment: Ah, I don't know of any throttling for an IP address. It could have been a temporary issue serving the file, or a simple DNS resolving problem. But the local fallback will work with any of the Google solutions, if you use Google's CDN or even Google Loader.

Comment: yep yep. don't worry. I know your solution is location-agnostic. :)

Comment: The issue started this morning, and has been going all day. (dns + trace routes seem to indicate good connection to their server/ip...but just doesn't respond). :(

Comment: I'd stop trying to hit `code.jquery.com` or the CDN that you're having issues with, or maybe contact your ISP? Depending on the need, and if you continue to have issues, you could edit the HOSTS file, or hijack the DNS at the firewall and redirect it to a local server that serves jQuery. It's be quite the hack, but all depends on the desperation.

Comment: Agreed. (like I said, not our code, others tend to use it).  ISP shouldn't be the issue from our investigating/testing with other IPs we have access to from the same ISP.  and yes, I did the redirect hosts file thing already to one of our local webservers ;).  The real kicker was that last night I told everyone that I'd had enough of the shenanigans and that I wasn't going to touch anything, and that I bet it would magically start working today...and low-and-behold...it is working this morning. so, go figure, lol.

Comment: *I will leave this question open for now, and will post if the problem happens again/if I learn anything. :)

Comment: I just witnessed the same.  Gave it a bit of time and it started loading again.